# examples of ring homomorphism $f : R → S$, where $R$ is arbitrary

Tags: ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

I've read the definition of the ring homomorphism:
**Definition**. Let $R$ and $S$ be rings. A ring homomorphism is a function $f : R → S$ such that:
(a) For all $x, y ∈ R, f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y).$
(b) For all $x, y ∈ R, f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$.
(c) $f(1) = 1.$

---

I want to see some examples of ring homomorphism $f : R → S$, where $R$ is arbitrary. So, I consider $S=R/I$ , where $I$ is an ideal of $R$. I can also imbed $R$ in a *Cartesian product*.

---

**What else?** Are there some *famous*  ring homomorphisms $f : R \to S$ for $R$  arbitrary?

---

Thank you.

Comment: Another important examples is the inclusion of a domain into the field of fractions which is very similar to the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Another trivial example is $f\colon R\rightarrow 0$ for the null ring. Or the identity $id:R\rightarrow R$ for an arbitrary ring $R$. What about more interesting ring homomorphisms than the ones from "arbitrary" $R$ ?

Comment: There is a natural ring homomorphism $R\rightarrow {\rm End}(R)$ to the endomorphism ring of $R$, given by $r\mapsto f_r$ with $f_r(a)=ra$.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde  f:R→0 for the null ring Or the identity id:R→R for an arbitrary ring, are special cases of $f:R \to R/I$, arent?

Comment: The First Isomorphism Theorem tells you that every ring homomorphism $f\colon R\to S$ can be viewed as the composition of a map $\pi\colon R\to R/I$, where $I$ is an ideal, followed by an inclusion of $R/I$ to $S$, i.e., identifying $R/I$ with a subring of $S$. So in a sense, the ring homomorphism $R\to R/I$, and inclusions of subrings into rings, are the "only" ring homomorphisms.

Comment: yes, thank you very much. Helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f : R \to R[x]$, where $x$ is an indeterminate.
$f : R \to S^{-1} R$, where $S$ is a  multiplicatively closed subset of $R$ (localization).

Comment: Or more generally: any inclusion map of a subring into a ring. Note, user1401, that this generic example, together with the one you gave ($R\to R/I$) are sufficient (any ring homomorphism $f$ is of equal to $g\circ h$ where $h$ is a quotient map and $g$ an inclusion map).

Comment: can u please explain this or maybe post it as an answer? @AnneBauval

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: For any ring homomorphism $f:R\to T,$ let $U=f(R)\simeq R/\ker g,$ $h:R\to U,\,r\mapsto f(r),$ and $g:U\to T,\,u\mapsto u.$ Then $h$ is (identifiable to) a quotient map, $g$ is an inclusion map, and $f=g\circ h.$ Besides, the two examples above are example of inclusion maps.

Answer (score 2):

$f\colon R\longrightarrow R\otimes_\mathbb{Z} S$,
given by $f(r)=r\otimes 1$, where $S$ is another unital ring.

$f\colon R\longrightarrow M_n(R)$, given by $f(r)=rI_n$, where $I_n$ is the identity matrix in $M_n(R)$.

Comment: Thank you very much